# Is this argument valid or invalid?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

For all n>1, $\frac{\arctan(n)}{n^3}$<$\frac{\pi}{2n^3}$, and the series $\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\frac{1}{n^3}$ converges, so by the comparison test, the series $\sum\frac{\arctan(n)}{n^3}$ converges.

Comment: You technically need the fact that $0\lt\arctan{(n)}/n^3$ as well.

Comment: However, with Peter Foreman's easily confirmed additional requirement, yes, that argument is valid. The partial sums of $\sum\frac{\arctan(n)}{n^3}$ form an increasing sequence which is bounded above by $\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\frac{1}{n^3}$ and therefore must converge.